# Why doesn't Ubuntu offer the same Online Accounts as Ubuntu Gnome?

Tags: gnome, online-accounts

Recently I loaded up Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 in VM's to look at and noticed that the number of Online Accounts offered far exceeds the number offered under regular Ubuntu. Since they are both Gnome based I wondered why this is the case?

In particular a couple of Ubuntu Gnome accounts missing from Ubuntu caught my attention: Microsoft Exchange, Own Cloud, Media Server.

.. So I went looking and found the [Online Accounts plugins page](https://launchpad.net/account-plugins) and it seems there is only Facebook and Google supported. I can't see plugins for the other services, so I guess that means the other accounts must be specific to Gnome.

Comment: You can easily install them to regular Ubuntu. And 16.04 is not released yet.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, I didn't realise you could install extra Online Accounts in Ubuntu. Do you happen to know what package names they are? And yes I know 16.04 is only in beta at the moment - prob should have said I was testing them and watching the progression of development.

Comment: See this http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/account-plugins

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Ubuntu does package things differently in their distro but luckily they don't remove the packages completely which means you can install any of the available Online account-plugins visible in gnome (plus others not visible) as per post from Pilot6

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and many other distributions make changes to what GNOME does. Ubuntu GNOME is trying to ship a more vanilla GNOME experience. However, even that project has to work around older packages in the Ubuntu repository.

So to answer your question, Ubuntu will modify GNOME however they see fit to provide the best fit for the Ubuntu ecosystem. The project still uses many of the GNOME programs and features in the standard release, but not everything. So there are parts of GNOME that don't come default with Ubuntu that can be added after install.

If you are looking for a better GNOME experience, then you should check out Fedora. That project is basically the gold standard for GNOME desktop.

Comment: I think you are correct Paul. I can vaguely remember something this effect being written about Online Accounts coming from Gnome when they first appeared in Ubuntu. It would also appear that as Pilot6 pointed out they are still available to be installed which is great as I wasn't aware.